# How to show status bar in UWP JavaScript app?

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

How to show the Windows 10 system status bar on mobile when writing the app in JavaScript? The `Windows.​UI.​View​Management.StatusBar` class is not available on Mobile, or so says Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the references to the UWP Mobile Extension, because the status bar only exists on Mobile.

[image]

Go to Project > Add References.

Check "Windows Mobile Extension for the UWP" and press "OK".

***WARNING***: You need to *check* if the API is present because the app can crash if it is not. Like this:

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.isTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar")) {

    let statusbar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.getForCurrentView();
    statusbar.showAsync();

}
```